# Is mold remediation effective in the long term?

Tags: mold, air-quality

Our home inspector just found serious mold problems in a home we are considering buying.

The seller are willing to pay for remediation, but I'm very concerned about the possibility that mold would return to the house later on.  Assuming that the underlying problems are corrected (cracks in the foundation, improper bathroom venting, etc.,) is it possible--or even likely that over the next 10 to 15 years, the problem could recur?

I'm concerned about the problem recurring in the existing locations, but just as much concerned that it could grow in other, hidden, yet-to-be-discovered/treated locations such as within walls, finished ceilings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A good remediation company will do testing on both surface and air afterwards.  I would make sure there is a good amount of time past after cleaning to go through and do the tests - a couple weeks maybe.

Your main concerns are basement and bathroom, so make them prove those areas too you.  If there is a lot of ongoing mold on a wall the it is likely it affected the surrounding areas.  So make them open up walls to prove there is nothing.  If they don't want to then I would expect the worst and know that first you might have more big issues that are hidden and two that you might need to do a lot of drywall and finishing touch work after you demo sheetrock in areas.

Note: I would also try to put some of the risk onto the remediation company.  If I have to use one on flips we go over everything.  I get a price.  And then if they mess up they come out and fix the area for free.  For instance if they tell you that you don't have mold in a room but find it a month later they would come out and remove wall and fix area.  You have to get a reputable company and then you will usually only be given 3-6 months.  If you think the house was full of moisture/humidity for a long time then I would assume that most of my drywall has to be replaced.  For a 2000 sq ft house that is 10-15K.   Also know too, mold needs moisture.  If there is a little mold in a wall and it never gets more moisture, there is little to no harm...  I will say this, I rather deal with termites than big mold when buying a house.